# Aireplay-ng - Deauth not working

Tags: aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

While using this command

`aireplay-ng --deauth 1000 -a <router mac address> -c <user mac address> interface name`

After hitting enter and sending two deauths, it says

```
write failed:Network is down
Wi_write() :Network is down
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the `[1| 0 ACKs]` you can see that both the router and client have a weak signal. Aireplay is sending 64 deauth packages for each the client and router. Only 1/64 deauth packages arrived at the router and 0/64 packages at the client, meaning you are out of range.

Now to the main part of your question.

```
write failed:Network is down
Wi_write() :Network is down
```

The error message indicates that there is a problem with your wireless interface. Run `lspci -k` to find out which exact WiFi chip is used and search the internet whether it supports monitor mode. Also try reinstalling the proper drivers with the chipset information gathered by the previously mentioned command and the [Debian Wiki - WiFi](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Install_Driver).

Comment: The clip I have is realtek rtl8192eu

Comment: And I am testing on my own router in my home than how its possible that I am out of range...

Comment: @Riyan Well either your Interface just has a worse range for some reason when being in monitor mode. Or your router encrypts  management frames, preventing deauth attacks.

Comment: Look at the `Pwr` value in airodump-ng, the closer its to 0, the better the range is

Comment: I analyzed my issue and came to know that I haven't installed my driver into kali linux so I will install the driver and than let you know if I  faced any  problem.